# Edit action has not been hitting while I push the submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatable, view, controller

I have an edit button in each row of my Datatable. I have two actions for editing. One for Getting data in a Datatable and the other one for posting my information. The code behind my Edit button in the my Home Index is:

```
{
 "data": "Id",
 "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
  return `<div class="text-center"> <a class="btn btn-info" 
      href="/Home/EditGet/` + data + `"   >Edit</a> </div> `;
}
```

and my home controller methods are:

/// Get Edit

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{Id}")]
    public IActionResult EditGet(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var obj = _sv.OpenRecord(id);
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        
        return View("EditGet", obj);
    }
```

/// Post Edit

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditPost(SalesVeiwModel sales)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           var res=  _sv.Update(sales.Comment);
            if (res==null )
            {
                return Json(data: "Not found");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("EditGet");
        }
            return Json(data: "Is not valid");
    }
```

---

And finally my EditGet view is like bellow:

```
  <form id="contact-form" method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-      
   action="EditPost" role="form" >
   <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Invoice Nomber</label>
   <input id="form_IBNo" type="text" class="form-control" disabled asp-for="IBNo">
   </div>
   .
   .
   .

   <div class="col-md-12">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Confirm"   asp- 
    controller="Home" asp-action="EditGet">
   </form>
```

Comment: In your `<input type=submit>` you don't need to include `asp-action` and `asp-controller` because that button is supposed to submit the form and will follow the url indicated in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Yes, your are right, but at first I don't put them and when I click on submit button in browser ,post method appear (/EditPost) .

Answer (score 0):

You should have two buttons,one call `EditGet`,one call `EditPost`,here is a demo:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-      
   action="EditPost" role="form" >
   <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Invoice Nomber</label>
   <input id="form_IBNo" type="text" class="form-control" disabled asp-for="IBNo">
   </div>
   .
   .
   .

   <div class="col-md-12">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Confirm">
   <a class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Confirm" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EditGet" asp-route-id="1">EditGet</a>
    </div>
   </form>
```